# Вывести YES , если число встречается в данном массиве, и NO в противном случае.Как добавить no?

Tags: c++

Пример:

Ввод:

> 5
>   1 2 3 4 5
>   3

Вывод:

> YES

Исходный код:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a,b=0,c; 

    cin>>a;

    int n[a];

    for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        cin>>n[i];
    }
    cin>>c;

    for(int j=0;j<a;j++)
    {
        if(n[j]==c)
        {
            b++;
            cout<<"YES";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Сделайте проверку при выходе из цикла был ли найден объект в напишите нет. или djcgjkmpeqntcm std::find, и замените массив на std::array

Comment: cin>>a;

int n[a]; - так на стеке массив не создать, ван нужно аллоцировать память.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы делал так:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a,c; 
    cin>>a;
    int * n = new int[a];

    for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        cin>>n[i];

    }
    cin>>c;
    for(int j=0;j<a;j++)
    {
        if(n[j]==c)
        {
            cout<<"YES\n";
            return 0;
        }
    }
    cout << "NO\n";
}
```